# ROS C++ serialization

Tags: c++, serialization, ros

I'm trying to serialize a message in C++ inside the framework ROS. My code is even working, it just seems so dirty. Is there a better way to do this? Cuz copying one buffer into another, doesn't seem like a very good solution performance-wise...

```
namespace ser = ros::serialization;  

void callback(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr & scan)                        
{                                                                                   
    trans = bp->lookupTransform("laser", "map", ros::Time(0));                      

    uint32_t scan_s = ros::serialization::serializationLength(*scan);               
    uint32_t trans_s = ros::serialization::serializationLength(trans);              

    ROS_INFO("Scan has serialization length: %i", scan_s);                          
    ROS_INFO("Trans has serialization length: %i", trans_s);                        

    /* Serialization: */                                                            
    char buffer_[scan_s];                                                           
    boost::shared_array<uint8_t> buffer(new uint8_t[scan_s]);                       

    ser::OStream stream(buffer.get(), scan_s);                                      
    ser::serialize(stream, *scan);                                                  

    for ( int i = 0; i < scan_s; i ++) {                                            
        buffer_[i] = buffer[i];                                                     
    }                                                                               

    ofstream output_file("test.data", ios::app);                                    
    output_file.write(buffer_, scan_s);                                             
    output_file.close();            
}
```

Also, what is that weird syntax `buffer(new ...)` saying? I can't even figure out how to call `delete` on that.

Further I'm not sure, whether copying the `buffer` object is even correct. What is the difference to `stream`?

Comment: `char buffer_[scan_s];` --  *it just seems so dirty* -- It is invalid, not just "dirty".  Arrays in C++ must have their sizes denoted by a constant expression, not a runtime expression.

Comment: *Also, what is that weird syntax `buffer(new ...)` saying? I can't even figure out how to call `delete` on that.* If you look at [the documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_array.htm) for `boost::shared_array` you'll see that it tells you exactly how you `delete` it. Note `shared_array` has been rendered obsolete in more recent versions of Boost.